# JPA Hibernate Stream Performance Issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using hibernate and JPA for fetching 50k data with stream from MySQL database, it scheduled around 5-15 minutes periodically.

this is my config of datasource

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=120000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout: 300000
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold: 300000
spring.datasource.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
```

here is the service class

```
@Service
public class BalanceReminderStream {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myServiceReminderEntityManager")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    Constant constant;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public boolean executeReminder(){

       //if another scheduling thread still running
       if(constant.activeReminder.containsKey(Context.BALANCE_REMINDER)){
           config.generalLogger.warn("Scheduling still running on another thread at "+constant.activeReminder.get(Context.BALANCE_REMINDER)+", skipping reminder");
           return false;
      }
      constant.activeReminder.put(Context.BALANCE_REMINDER, LocalDateTime.now());

      constant.streamBalanceReminder = userServiceReminderRepository.findAllActiveBalanceReminder();    

      //do get data
      constant.streamBalanceReminder.forEach(userServiceReminder -> {

            constant.fetchSizeBalanceReminder.getAndIncrement();

            //process each records, add to thread pool
            threadPoolManager.addBalanceReminderQueue(userServiceReminder);

            //detach the entity so garbage collector can reclaim the memory
            entityManager.detach(userServiceReminder);
        });
     }
     return true;
}
```

here is jpa

```
@Repository
public interface UserServiceReminderRepository extends JpaRepository<UserServiceReminder, Long>{
    @QueryHints(value = {
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE),
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"),
            @QueryHint(name = READ_ONLY, value = "true")
    })
    @Query("FROM #{#entityName} WHERE status = 'ACTIVE' AND status_reminder = 'BALANCE'")
    Stream<UserServiceReminder> findAllActiveBalanceReminder();
    }
}
```

and I call the component from scheduler class like this

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class BalanceReminderScheduler {
    @Autowired
    BalanceReminderStream balanceReminderStream;

    @Autowired
    Config config;

    @Autowired
    Constant constant;

@Async
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000L * 60 * 15)
void execute(){
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean isReminderExecuted = false;
        try {
            isReminderExecuted = balanceReminderStream.executeReminder();
        }catch (TransactionSystemException e){
            String stacktrace = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);
            config.generalLogger.error(stacktrace);
            //close stream
            if(constant.streamBalanceReminder!=null){
                constant.streamBalanceReminder.close();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            String stacktrace = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);
            config.generalLogger.error(stacktrace);
        }finally{
            if(isReminderExecuted) {
                config.generalLogger.info("Fetch size: " + constant.fetchSizeBalanceReminder.get()
                    + " (" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms)");
                 constant.activeReminder.remove(Context.BALANCE_REMINDER);
                 constant.fetchSizeBalanceReminder.set(0);
                 //close stream
                 if(constant.streamBalanceReminder!=null){
                     constant.streamBalanceReminder.close();
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

for first time run, it doesn't get any exception, and the fetch time still about 10 seconds, but after 3 hours, the fetch time getting slowed down drastically and then got an exception

[image: fetch time log]

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to rollback against JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:593)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:835)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:809)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:672)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.sample.myapp.service.reminder.BalanceReminderStream$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee49a3b6.executeReminder(<generated>)
    at com.sample.myapp.scheduler.BalanceReminderScheduler.execute(BalanceReminderScheduler.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:774)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to rollback against JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:142)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:589)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ResultsetRowsStreaming@76fa3328 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollbackNoChecks(ConnectionImpl.java:1951)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:1845)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:396)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:121)
    ... 26 more
```

after that, it will always get an exception until I restart the java, is there any I missed here?

Comment: Hard to say what is going on without seeing the full code. It seems that you have some sort of connection/resource leak though. Not sure what Spring Data does when you request a `Stream` to be returned from a repository. Try to time `findAllActiveBalanceReminder` and `addBalanceReminderQueue` separately as well to see if the time to execute these tasks increases as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that every query is done with processing before another query starts?
Maybe it is stacking data, and that's why you are getting longer processing times.
Just an idea.

Also, you can try to run it with a CPU profiler to check what is taking the most of the time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure on it, actually I already add the code to check is the thread of fetching data still running (I've edited on my code), sometimes I got log that the thread still active